# Zabbix - custom intervals for agent active checks

Tags: zabbix

`Zabbix agent` passive checks items have `update interval` and `custom intervals` fields which allows to specify exact check execution time.

When changing item type to `Zabbix agent (active)` only `Update interval` field is available.

I need some checks to be executed at specified hour 11:00, 12:00, and so on. Specifying `update interval` to `1h` will execute check every hour, but this may be 11:31, 12:31 and so on.

Is there way to force active checks to run at specified moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible currently, you might want to vote on the [feature request](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-693).